# Getting HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request response

Tags: java, http-post

Request header After login to webapp is as below

```
Accept            application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control     no-cache
Connection        keep-alive
Content-Length    5195
Content-Type      application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie            JSESSIONID=DC83EEF14C3B1F309ADF125B92A62629; _ga=GA1.2.1119685758.1496394454; _gid=GA1.2.682909819.1496644441
Host              gpsdevci.pdx.aws
Pragma            no-cache
Referer           http://sample URL
User-Agent        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
X-CSRF-Token      a92b8e7c-8f50-4d64-8290-58409b481109
X-CSRF-Uri        /cgw/cases/listAsJSON
X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest
```

code I am using is as below

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://gpsdevci.pdx.aws/cgw-api/v2.0.0/case");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"panelName\":\"comprehensive_cancer_panel_version_3\",\"sampleType\":\"patientcare\",\"indication\":\"Identified Indication\",\"disease\":{\"code\":\"254837009\",\"label\":\"Malignant tumor of breast\"},\"physicians\":[{\"firstName\":\"fName\",\"lastName\":\"lName\"}],\"identified\":true,\"specimens\":[{\"name\":\"primarySpecimen\",\"type\":{\"code\":\"441652008\",\"label\":\"Formalin-fixed paraffin-embedded tissue specimen\"},\"accessionNumber\":\"abc\",\"dateAccessioned\":\"2016-03-29T20:00:00Z\",\"datecollected\":\"2016-03-29T20:00:00Z\",\"dateReceived\":\"2016-03-29T20:00:00Z\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"2001-10-12\",\"firstName\":\"fname\",\"lastName\":\"Lname\",\"medicalRecordNumbers\":[{\"medicalFacility\":{\"hospitalNumber\": \"1\",\"facility\": \"TEST facility\"},\"mrn\":\"MRN1\"}],\"clientName\":\"GPS\"}]}");

        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        //request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", HeaderOAuth);

        request.addHeader("Content-type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        request.addHeader("Accept","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
        request.addHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0");
        request.addHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5");
        request.addHeader("Cookie","JSESSIONID=DC83EEF14C3B1F309ADF125B92A62629; _ga=GA1.2.1119685758.1496394454; _gid=GA1.2.682909819.1496644441");
        request.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.addHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "5ba25ce0-b5b5-40aa-b38d-44234237e7fb");
        request.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        request.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        request.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

After executing code getting below response

```
    response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 11:17:21 GMT, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9FF5F2DD2BAEC9248B0C2A04A58BCC57; Path=/cgw-api/; Secure; HttpOnly, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: 0, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, X-Frame-Options: DENY, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Connection: close, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8,Chunked: true]}}
```

please provide suggestion I tried all things

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer but I can't comment yet.

I guess you got the header by manually requesting the server on a web browser, and just captured the network stuff (F12 on Mozilla).

So, I think your problem maybe due to the X-CSRF-Token value. Try to get an other header like you did to get your first one, and see if the X-CSRF-Token value is the same as before.

X-CSRF-Token is a security token, and it keeps changing everytime. See more here : [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Comment: yes you are correct @Asew, X-CSRF-Token is keep on changing every time but if I remove that from my code then also I am getting 400 bad request. X-CSRF-Token is compulsory to add in header if yes then how to fetch each time new token please give solution

Comment: Do you have access to the sourcecode of the web page from your code ?

Comment: I will check and let you know

Comment: I can able to access source code of Login page through java code